# Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
var navStates = [true, false, false, false, false];
var history = [];
var historyPos = 0;
var havingAWebsite = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#infozion").trigger("focus");
    $("#content").hide().load("index_content.php").fadeIn("1000");
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
    $(".navbar-brand").click(function() {
        $("#content").hide().load("index_content.php").fadeIn("300");
        navStates[0] = true; navStates[1] = false;
        navStates[2] = false; navStates[3] = false; navStates[4] = false;
        history.push(0);
        historyPos = history.length - 1;
        havingAWebsite = false;
    });
    $(".navbar-nav a:eq(0)").click(function() {
        $("#content").hide().load("services.php").fadeIn("300");
        navStates[0] = false; navStates[1] = true;
        navStates[2] = false; navStates[3] = false; navStates[4] = false;
        history.push(1);
        historyPos = history.length - 1;
        havingAWebsite = false;
    });
    $(".navbar-nav a:eq(1)").click(function() {
        $("#content").hide().load("tech.php").fadeIn("300");
        navStates[0] = false; navStates[1] = false;
        navStates[2] = true; navStates[3] = false; navStates[4] = false;
        history.push(2);
        historyPos = history.length - 1;
        havingAWebsite = false;
    });
    $(".navbar-nav a:eq(2)").click(function() {
        $("#content").hide().load("about.php").fadeIn("300");
        navStates[0] = false; navStates[1] = false;
        navStates[2] = false; navStates[3] = true; navStates[4] = false;
        history.push(3);
        historyPos = history.length - 1;
        havingAWebsite = false;
    });
    $(".navbar-nav a:eq(3)").click(function() {
        $("#content").hide().load("contact.php").fadeIn("300");
        navStates[0] = false; navStates[1] = false;
        navStates[2] = false; navStates[3] = false; navStates[4] = true;
        history.push(4);
        historyPos = history.length - 1;
        havingAWebsite = false;
    });
});
```

The `history.push(0);` gives me Uncaught TypeError, which makes no sense, since history **is** an array and push **is** a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`history` is actually a read-only property of the window and is an instance of [`History` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history).  You may want to rename your variables to something else to make things work

Comment: Or just move the variable declarations inside the `document.ready` function.